# Best practice for returning an error from a lua function returning multiple values

Tags: lua

I have a lua function which takes multiple parameters and returns as many values as there are parameters. Each return value corresponds to a parameter. To illustrate, consider a function which reads the value for a key/value pair from a database:

```
val1, val2, val3 = my_function("key1", "key2", "key3");
val1 = my_function("key1");
```

**What is the best way to return an error from `my_function`?** (e.g. if a supplied "key" is invalid)

I understand one way is to return two values on error, `nil` and an error string. Is this the best approach? For example:

```
val1, val2, val3 = my_function("key1", "key2", "key3");
if val1 then
    -- Use val1, val2, and val3.
else
    print("ERROR: " .. val2);
end
```

**Edit**

Some additional points:

1. The lua script is being executed from within a C program using `lua_pcall()`.
2. The C program must not abort if the script fails.
3. `my_function()` is implemented in C.
4. When `my_function()` fails, it should also return an error code (or message) indicating the reason it failed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard way of throwing errors in Lua is via the error function ([manual](http://www.lua.org/pil/8.3.html), [api](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-error)) or via [assert](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-assert) (which internally uses `error` anyway).

Since your function is in C, you should be calling [lua_error](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_error) inside it, to gain the same effect.

But keep in mind that your function now is "insecure". If unmodified, the following code will do the equivalent of "throwing an exception" and thus halting the program, if key1, key2 or key3 are "erroneous":

```
val1, val2, val3 = my_function("key1", "key2", "key3")
```

Sometimes it's ok to let the program "just crash" if the inputs are wrong. Depending on your setup, the user will get a message with the last error, and a stack trace, or something along those lines.

If "letting the program crash" is not an option, you can do the equivalent of surrounding it with a "try-catch" block by using the [pcall](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-pcall) function, and adding a new variable called `ok`:

```
ok, val1, val2, val3 = pcall(my_function, "key1", "key2", "key3")
if ok then
  -- Use val1, val2, and val3.
else
  print("ERROR: " .. val1) -- notice that we use val1 here, not val2
end
```

Notice that you don't have to put `pcall` exactly on top of `my_function`. As with exceptions, the error recuperation can happen higher in the call chain: in the function calling `my_function`, or the function calling that one, etc. For example, if you call `my_function` from a function called `parent`, and parent from one called `grandParent`, you can do this:

```
-- parent is "insecure" since my_function is "unprotected"
function parent(key1, key2)
  local val1, val2, val3 = my_function(key1, key2, "key3")
  return val1, val2, val3
end

-- grandParent calls parent in a "safe" way
function grandParent()
  local ok, val1, val2, val3 = pcall(parent, "key1", "key2")
  if ok then
    -- Use val1, val2, and val3.
  else
    print("ERROR: " .. val1)
  end
end
```

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify a few points. Since the lua script (which eventually calls `my_function()`) is run from C with `lua_pcall()`, should `my_function()` return an "ok" variable as you described above? (e.g. `ok, val1, val2, val3 = my_function()`).

Comment: @Ben, yes, I would include an additional `ok` value - that seems to be the cleanest way. I would also recommend a revision in the design; since both functions are in C, it's probably going to be simpler (and faster) to forget about Lua and just do everything in C.

Comment: @kikto, thanks for clarifying. In this case it definitely makes sense for me to use lua (or an equivalent) for extending the product.

Comment: @Ben There is a drawback to this approach: there is no clean way to distinguish between an error in single and in multiple parameters (say, key1 does exist, but either key2 nor key3). You can either not bother; provide different error messages; or instead of returning a single value per parameter always return 2 (`ok1, val1, ok2, val2` etc); or in case of error return a table with error info (will only work if usually the return value is not a table).

Answer (score 0):

The usual practice is to throw errors when the program cannot recover (bad file handle for instance) and signal errors when it can recover (file not found for instance). In your case, I think that simply returning `nil` for invalid keys is the best way.

Comment: If I want my_function() to also return the reason it failed, are you advocating that if `val1, val2, val3 = my_function()` fails, `val1` should be `nil` and `val2` should be the error code/message?

Comment: @Ben, no, I thought the only reason was "invalid key".